# What does this typedef definition mean?

Tags: c++, typedef

I have seen the following (C++):

```
typedef n *(m)(const n*, const n*);
```

What does it mean and how can it be used?

I understand this:

```
typedef n (*myFunctP)(const n*, const n*);
```

but what is the difference to the typedef above?

(Hope this is no duplicate, did not find something similar...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I asked [geordi](http://www.eelis.net/geordi/) to win me some rep:

```
<tomalak> << TYPE_DESC<m>; struct n {}; typedef n *(m)(const n*, const n*);
<geordi> function taking 2 pointers to constant ns and returning a pointer to a n
```

C type declaration syntax is *horrible* and it does become particularly apparent when you start doing complex declarations like this. Notice how the return type and arguments are written around the `m`, not the `n`, which is totally backwards to intuition since it's `m` that you're creating.

Your second example is:

```
<tomalak> << TYPE_DESC<m>; struct n {}; typedef n (*m)(const n*, const n*);
<geordi> pointer to a function taking 2 pointers to constant ns and returning a n
```

By moving the `*`, you are no longer applying it to the function type's return type, but to the function type itself.

In C++11, unless you have a desperate need for your calls to be hyper-efficient, please stick to the following, for the love of Cthulhu! :-)

```
typedef std::function<n*(const n*, const n*)> m;
```

If you wish to stick to function pointers then you can:

```
using m = n*(const n*, const n*);
```

Prior to that you can use `boost::function` or learn the horrific C declarator rules. It is true that you should know them; it's just that hopefully you won't *have* to use them too often.

Comment: I agree 100% with your conclusion. People in the C++ world really need to start using std::function to express function pointers. Ignore the (very outdated) Google style guide and use std::function, for the love of tentacle monster gods!

Comment: Or better: `using m = n*(const n*, const n*);`

Comment: @MattHolmes:  It is still necessary to understand and be able to write the pre-`function` syntax.  Not everybody uses C++11 or Boost.

Comment: Is `std::function` overhead free?

Comment: @RedX: No. You get an overhead roughly equivalent to virtual calls, sometimes. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5057382/560648

Comment: @JohnDibling: Boost has provided the 'function' template for nearly a decade, and it's been part of the C++ standard for over two years. People need to get with the times. If you are writing new code and not using std::function (or it's Boost equivalent) it's likely you're being a grognard and nothing more. Old code bases are a different monster.

Comment: @RedX: Not enough of one that you should care about it. It's about the same as a virtual function call, and if you're doing that sort of micro-optimization you shouldn't be writing C++ anyway. You should be writing raw C or assembly.

Comment: "Cthulhu" and not "Chulthu" :-)

Comment: @MattHolmes:  It's not that simple.  Consider for example that the version of GCC that comes with the RHEL distro is quite old, far pre-C++11.  Many software and client shops *require* that the toolchain provided with the distro be used.  Try to see the bigger picture before assuming all who don't share *your* beliefs to be "grognards".

Comment: @MattHolmes: To be fair there is still legacy and there are still lightweight systems. Introducing templated virtual calls and 3rd party libraries is not always okay. We don't all program for desktop PCs. I would disagree with the conclusion in that scenario is "well you shouldn't be using C++", but I _would_ agree that you're obviously not going to be using all of C++'s features, which is the case here.

Comment: I think: `typedef n* (m)(const n*, const n*);` is easier to read than: `typedef n *(m)(const n*, const n*);` Maybe that is what confused OP? Well that's where I got lost anyway. The star being on the n vs. being on the bracket.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: I agree. In fact: http://kera.name/articles/2010/05/tomalaks-monday-monstrous-rant-i-align-your-asterisks/ However, even that does start to break down when the declarators become _this_ complicated.

Answer (score 5):

The first typedef creates an alias for a function which takes 2 parameters and returns a pointer-to-`n`.

The second typedef creates an alias for a *pointer-to-*function which takes 2 parameters and returns an `n` *by value*.

Comment: Whether the `*` is inside or outside the parentheses makes a difference.

Comment: Oddly enough, I cannot undo my vote, even though you clearly did edit your answer. SO still says my vote is locked unless this answer is edited.

Comment: @hvd:  Probably some kind of bug with the SE platform having to do with the fact that I edited before I un-deleted.  Don't worry about it; the rep's not a big deal.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  It's odd that the edit history does not give any indication that I edited this post.

Comment: Done. I think it may be because edit history remains empty during the first five-or-so minutes after posting an answer, and the vote locking relies on edit history.

Comment: @hvd:  That must be it.  In any case, I opened a meta ticket about the edit history:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215153/odd-behavior-in-edit-history-when-i-edited-my-deleted-answer

Answer (score 1):

In the first case the typedef defines an alias for a function type that has two parameters of type `const n *`and return type `n *`

In the second case instead of the function type there is a declaration of a function pointer having return type n.

In the first case you could write also for example

```
typedef n * ( (m)(const n*, const n*) );
```

It is equivalent to your typedef.

As for the usage you can use it as a function declaration. For exmaple

```
m MyFunc;
```

Another example

```
struct A
{
   typedef int n;
   typedef n  ( Operation )( n, n ) const;
   Operation Add;
   Operation Subtract;
   Operation Division;
   Operation Multiply;
};

// and below the function definitions
```