# How to initialize `std::function` with a member-function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to learn `std::function` and here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Foo {
    void print_add(int i){ 
      std::cout << i << '\n'; 
    }
};

typedef std::function<void(int)> fp;

void test(fp my_func)
{
  my_func(5);
}

int main(){
    Foo foo;
    test(foo.print_add);
    return 0;
}
```

**Compiler Error:**

```
 error: cannot convert 'Foo::print_add' from type 'void (Foo::)(int)' to type 'fp {aka std::function<void(int)>}'
     test(foo.print_add);
```

How can I make this work, i.e how can I pass a member function as a parameter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using generic std::function objects with member functions in one class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582546/using-generic-stdfunction-objects-with-member-functions-in-one-class)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`print_add` is a non-static member function of `foo`, which means it must be invoked on an instance of `Foo`; hence it has an implicit first argument, the `this` pointer.

Use a lambda that captures the `foo` instance and invokes `print_add` on it.

```
Foo foo;
test([&foo](int i){ foo.print_add(i); });
```

Another option is to use `std::bind` to bind the `foo` instance:

```
test(std::bind(&Foo::print_add, &foo, std::placeholders::_1));
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22acb8a78118f357)

Comment: Can you explain a bit how this works please? i.e. if this is first argument then how come it is the second one in bind(...)?

Comment: @Kam The first argument to `bind` is a pointer to the member function. The second argument onward are the ones the get passed to that member function when you invoke the `std::function`. Thus the pointer to `foo` gets passed as the first argument to `print_add` (the `this` pointer) when you invoke callable within `test`. The `placeholders::_1` means that you'll supply that argument later, and the first argument you give to the callable (`5`) will be passed along as the second argument to `print_add` (since that's the position the placeholder appears at).

Comment: @Kam [This page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) has an excellent example on using `bind` and shows how moving placeholders can be used to achieve different results.

Comment: Last Question :) which one is preferred here? lambda or bind? performance wise?

Comment: @Kam You're sticking both into an `std::function`, and there is a [performance overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057382/what-is-the-performance-overhead-of-stdfunction) associated with using one of those, that should be about the same as using a virtual function call. The `bind` itself shouldn't be adding any overhead, but to be honest, I have no idea. I'd personally use the lambda in this case.

Answer (score 9):

You need an object to call a non-static member function. Hence, when you want to get a `std::function` you have several options:

- make the method static
- bind an object to the `std::function` via lambda
- bind an object to the `std::function` via custom functor
- pass the object when the `std::function` is called

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct A {
    int i = 42;
    int get() const { return i; }    
    
    static int get_static() { return 0; }
};

struct A_functor {
    A a;    
    int operator()() const { return a.get(); }
};

int main() {    

    // static method
    std::function<int()> f1 = &A::get_static;
    std::cout << f1() << "\n";

    // bind an object to the function via lambda
    A a;
    std::function<int()> f2 = [&a](){ return a.get(); };
    std::cout << f2() << "\n";

    // store the object in the std::function
    std::function<int()> f3 = A_functor{};
    std::cout << f3() << "\n";
    // or 
    std::function<int()> f4 = [a = A()](){ return a.get(); };
    std::cout << f4() << "\n";

    // pass the object when the std::function is called
    std::function<int(A&)> f5 = &A::get;
    std::cout << f5(a) << "\n";
    // or 
    std::function<int(A*)> f6 = &A::get;
    std::cout << f6(&a) << "\n";
    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**THE PROBLEM**

You cannot directly bind a *member-function pointer* belonging to type `Foo` to `std::function<void(int)>`, specifically because calling a non-static *member-function* requires an instance of type `Foo`.

```
Foo obj; obj.member_function (); // can't call `member_function` without `obj`
```

---

<sup>**Note**: You can however bind `&Foo::print_add` to `std::function<void(Foo&, int)> x;`, and call it as `x(instance_of_Foo, arg);`.</sup>

<sup>**Note**: It's also possible to bind it to `std::function<void(Foo*, int>`, which would require a `Foo*` instead of an *lvalue* of type `Foo`.</sup>

---

---

**THE SOLUTION**

Instead you can use `std::bind` to *bind*  an instance of `Foo` to the member-function in question, such as in the below example:

```
int main(){
    Foo foo;
    test (std::bind (&Foo::print_add, foo, std::placeholders::_1));
    return 0;
}
```

<sup>Above we bind an instance of `Foo` named `foo` to the *member-function pointer* `&Foo::print_add`.</sup>

---

The usage of `std::placeholders::_1` tells `std::bind` that we'd like it to generate a *function-object* that is callable using one (1) argument.

With the above snippet you will have the behaviour that you are currently asking for; `my_func(5)` will be equivalent of calling `foo.print_add (5)`.

---

**DOCUMENTATION**

- [**`std::function`** - cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)
- [**`std::bind`** - cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)
- [**`std::placeholders`** - cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders)

Comment: The first sentence isn't quite accurate, you can't bind `Foo::print_add` to `std::function<void(int)>` but can bind it to `std::function<void(Foo&, int)>` or `std::function<void(Foo*, int)>`