# Function pointer c++

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers, function-pointers

I am trying to use a function pointer on functions of class `DPkDispersionMemNK`.

I don't understand why it doesn't work

Can you help me please?

the code in DPkDispersionMemKN.hpp :

```
#include "DPkDispersion.hpp"

class DPkDispersionMemKN : public DPkDispersion {
protected:

    float** matrixDP;
    std::pair<float,int> (DPkDispersionMemKN::*func)(int k, int i);

public:
    std::pair<float,int> computeDich(int k, int i);
    std::pair<float,int> computeSum(int k, int i);
    std::pair<float,int> computeMin(int k, int i);

    void setfunc( std::pair<float,int> (&fonction)(int, int)) { func= fonction;};
};
```

and the 3 functions I wish I could use a pointer on them: (they are in the DPkDispersionMemKN.cpp) (it's not really important)

```
std::pair<float,int> DPkDispersionMemKN::computeSum(int k, int i) {
    float max=0;
    int ind= 0;

    for (int j = k - 1; j <= i - 1; j++ ) {
        if (matrixDP[k-1][j] + dist(j, i) > max) {
            max = matrixDP[k-1][j] + dist(j, i);
            ind = j;
        }
    }

    return make_pair(max,ind);
}

std::pair<float,int> DPkDispersionMemKN::computeMin(int k, int i) {
    float max=0;
    int ind= 0;

    for (int j = k - 1; j <= i - 1; j++) {
        if (min(matrixDP[k-1][j], dist(j, i)) > max){
            max = min(matrixDP[k-1][j], dist(j, i));
            ind = j;
        }
    }

    return make_pair(max,ind);
}

std::pair<float,int> DPkDispersionMemKN::computeDich(int k, int i) {
    int j;
    int a=k-1;
    int b = i-1;
    while (b-a >= 2) {
        j = (i+(a+b)) / 2;

        if (matrixDP[k-1][j]-dist(j, i) > 0) {
            b = j;
        } else {
            a = j;
        }
    }

    if (min(matrixDP[k-1][a], dist(a, i)) < min(matrixDP[k-1][b], dist(b, i))) {
        return make_pair(min(matrixDP[k-1][b], dist(b, i)), b);
    } else {
        return make_pair(min(matrixDP[k-1][a], dist(a, i)), a);
    }
}
```

and Finaly, in the main.cpp:

```
solver3.setfunc(&DPkDispersionMemKN::computeMin);
```

I wish I could choose in the main witch function I want to use but it's not working.

Thank you for your help!

```
In file included from DPkDispersionMemKN.cpp:1:
./DPkDispersionMemKN.hpp:35:68: error: assigning to 'std::pair<float, int>
      (DPkDispersionMemKN::*)(int, int)' from incompatible type
      'std::pair<float, int> (int, int)'
  ...setfunc( std::pair<float,int> (&fonction)(int, int)) { func= fonction;};
                                                                  ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: *function pointers*, and *pointer on function members* are different beasts.

Comment: In the future you may want to consider this approach: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962019/how-to-initialize-stdfunction-with-a-member-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962019/how-to-initialize-stdfunction-with-a-member-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
void setfunc(std::pair<float,int> (DPkDispersionMemKN::*fonction)(int, int)) { func = fonction;}
```

And usage similar to:

```
std::pair<float, int> res = (this->*func)(someI, someJ);
```

Answer (score 0):

You used the wrong type in `setfunc`. The compiler even tells you (emphasis mine):

> In file included from DPkDispersionMemKN.cpp:1:
>   ./DPkDispersionMemKN.hpp:35:68: error: assigning to '
>       **std::pair<float, int> (DPkDispersionMemKN::*)(int, int)**
>   ' from incompatible type '
>       **std::pair<float, int> (int, int)**

`std::pair<float, int> (DPkDispersionMemKN::*)(int, int)` is the function type. But that is not the type you have used when declaring `setfunc`'s parameter. You have used a different type there. Change it to the correct type.

Comment: void setfunc(std::pair<float,int> (DPkDispersionMemKN::*fonction)(int, int)) { func = fonction;}

Comment: In file included from DPkDispersionMemKN.cpp:1:
./DPkDispersionMemKN.hpp:30:58: error: expected unqualified-id
        void setfunc( std::pair<float,int> (DPkDispersionMemKN::&fonctio...
                                                                ^

Comment: @Camille10 did you know that & and * are not the same letter?

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to a non static member function needs an instance of the class to be called.

```
std::pair<float,int> (DPkDispersionMemKN::*func)(int k, int i);
DPkDispersionMemKN d;
auto p = (d.*)func(1, 2);

std::pair<float,int> (*f)(int, int);
auto p2 = f(1, 2);
```

That's the reason why you get a compilation error.
Depending on what you need you can change the methods to being static or you can switch to [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)