# Why the Man or Boy test seem much faster in Objective-C (blocks) than in C++ (lambda)?

Tags: gcc, optimization, lambda, clang, objective-c-blocks

I've got an assignment for "performance analysis" class and decided to do some testing in gcc and clang using the [Man or Boy test](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Man_or_boy_test). I've completed my assignment already, but something odd came up.

The Objective-C code (no ARC!) with blocks is as follow:

```
#import <stdlib.h>
#import <assert.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef int (^F)(void);

int A(int kParam, F x1, F x2, F x3, F x4, F x5) {
  __block int k = kParam;
  __block F B;

  B = ^ {
    return A(--k, B, x1, x2, x3, x4);
  };
  return k <= 0 ? x4() + x5() : B();
};

F K(int n) {
    return [[^{
                return n;
              } copy] autorelease];
};

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
  static int TABLE[] = {1, 0, -2, 0, 1, 0, 1, -1, -10, -30, -67, -138, -291,
                        -642, -1446, -3250};

  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  if(argc == 2) {
    int k;
    sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &k);
    int result = A(k, K(1), K(-1), K(-1), K(1), K(0));
    assert(result == TABLE[k]);
  };
  [pool drain];

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
};
```

And the C++ code I used is as follow:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <tr1/functional> // I'm using tr1 because I have an old version of libstdc++
using namespace std;
using namespace std::tr1;

typedef function<int()> F;

int A(int k, const F &x1, const F &x2, const F &x3, const F &x4, const F &x5) {
  F B = [=, &k, &B] {
    return A(--k, B, x1, x2, x3, x4);
  };
  return k <= 0 ? x4() + x5() : B();
};

F L(int n) {
  return [n] {
    return n;
  };
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  static int TABLE[] = {1, 0, -2, 0, 1, 0, 1, -1, -10, -30, -67, -138, -291,
                        -642, -1446, -3250};

  if(argc == 2) {
    int k;
    sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &k);
    int result = A(k, L(1), L(-1), L(-1), L(1), L(0));
    assert(result == TABLE[k]);
  };

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
};
```

The Objective-C version seems to perform quite good (I tested with `k` ranging from 1 to 15) on both clang 3.5 and llvm-gcc 4.2. The C++ version, on the other hand, took around 9 seconds with `k` as 15 on both clang 3.5 and gcc 4.9.

Am I missing something? Why is the C++ version so much slower at higher values? ([Here's the data table I generated to use in R](http://pastebin.com/VhJgGhq2), in case anyone wants to check.)

## Edit:

Looks like the overhead came from `std::function<>`, as stated in the comments. In case anyone ever needs, using [this replacement](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14730/impossibly-fast-delegate-in-c11) instead resolved the issue, and it got (a little bit) faster than Objective-C, as one would expect.

Comment: `std::function` is not recommended for performance critical code. Just use plain lambdas or templates. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057382/what-is-the-performance-overhead-of-stdfunction

Comment: also `trx` implementations are usually **not** optimized

Comment: I thought so, and I managed to test it again with an updated libstdc++. Still was slowing down as the number increased. I'm gonna try getting rid of std::function<> to see what happens!

Comment: C++ and Swift are very sensitive to optimisations turned on or not, Objective-C much less so. Check your optimiser settings.

Comment: @gnasher729, I tested it with -O0, -Os, -O1, -O2 and -O3. Almost no difference (check table file).

Comment: @bolov, changing `A` to be a templated function gave some improvement, but I couldn't completly remove std::function<> because of my `B` lambda (which is recursive). Any ideas?

Comment: `auto B = ` doesn't work?

Comment: No, but [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14730/impossibly-fast-delegate-in-c11) worked like a charm! :)

Comment: @bolov: `std::function` is for erasing the callable type to a common callable type. That's exactly what is needed in this case.