# How properly pass comparator to another template function

Tags: c++, templates

I need a function that will take two iterators and a custom comparator to compare values of this iterators. I don't want use additional template argument for this. I've implemented it in this way:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T begin, T end,
  function<bool(decltype(*begin), decltype(*begin))> compare = less<decltype(*begin)>())
{
    // I want to use 'compare' as: "compare(*begin, *begin);"
}
```

This code has been compiled normally by clang, but on GCC 5.4.0 I've got some errors:

```
binary_heap.cpp:10:79: error: local variable 'begin' may not appear in this context
   function<bool(decltype(*begin), decltype(*begin))> compare = less<decltype(*begin)>())
                                                                               ^
binary_heap.cpp:10:85: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   function<bool(decltype(*begin), decltype(*begin))> compare = less<decltype(*begin)>())
```

How to correct this code so that it can be successfully compiled on both clang and GCC? Or maybe are there a more suitable solution for defining such function?

Comment: Why do you not want to use an additional template argument for this?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use a parameter in a default argument, even in an unevaluated context (although the Standard should probably be amended to loosen that restriction). Instead of `decltype(*begin)`, use

```
decltype(*std::declval<T&>())
```

*Edit:* Actually, that probably doesn't do what you want, since if applying the `*` operator yields an lvalue, then the `decltype` specifier will resolve to an lvalue reference, but you would want the unreferenced type to be the argument to `std::less`. Better to use:

```
typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type
```

*Edit 2:* I agree with krzaq, it's better to just add another template parameter.

Answer (score 4):

You're pessimizing performance of your algorithm by a lot just by forcing the use of `function` (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057382/what-is-the-performance-overhead-of-stdfunction)). Just take template deduced `Compare` and you're golden:

```
template<typename T, typename Compare = std::less<typename iterator_traits<T>::value_type>>
void foo(T begin, T end, Compare compare = {})
{
    // I want to use 'compare' as: "compare(*begin, *begin);"
}
```

Interestingly, standard algorithms force/suggest use of lightweight functors by taking them by value instead of a forwarding reference.

---

To answer the actual question: you can use `std::less<>`, which defaults to `std::less<void>` and has templated `operator()` doing the actual comparisons:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T begin, T end,
  function<bool(decltype(*begin), decltype(*begin))> compare = less<>())
{
    // I want to use 'compare' as: "compare(*begin, *begin);"
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, in what ways do you pessimize the performance by using `function`?

Comment: @krzaq Thank you! If I interested in best performance, what kind of solution should I choose?

Comment: @0x1337 I'd pass a template parameter without much interference. It makes for slightly worse error messages (hopefully to be fixed with concepts), but is readable, fast and consistent with the standard library. Look how `Compare` is taken by [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

Comment: I'd use `{}` instead of `Compare{}` following DRY.

Answer (score 3):

Add another template parameter `Compare`.  This makes inlining easier by the compiler.  While I'm at it support Sentinels.

```
template<class It, class Sentinel, class Compare=std::less<void>>
void foo(It begin, Sentinel end, Compare cmp={}) {
}
```

However, assuming C++14, barring the above, I'd do this:

```
template<class T>
using comparator_sig = bool(T const&,T const&);
template<class T>
using comparator = std::function<comparator_sig<T>>;
template<class It>
using compare_inside_it = comparator<
  typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type
>;

template<typename T>
void foo(T begin, T end, compare_inside_it<T> compare = less<>) {
}
```

in C++11 I would write my own `less<void>`:

```
struct compare_less {
  template<class T>
  bool operator()( T const& lhs, T const& rhs ) const {
    return std::less<T>{}(lhs, rhs);
  }
};
```

and do:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T begin, T end, compare_inside_it<T> compare = compare_less{}) {
}
```

or even just do:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T begin, T end, compare_inside_it<T> compare = {}) {
  if (!compare) compare=compare_less{};
}
```