# is std::function heavier than auto storing lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, auto, std-function

I heard that cost of `std::function` is heavier than `auto` to deal with a lambda function. effective modern c++ item5. What I want is to clarify the mechanism why `std::function` use more memory than `auto` with some sample code.
Could somebody help me?

edit

```
class Widget {
public:
  Widget(int i) : i_(i) {}
  bool operator<(const Widget& o) { return o.value() > i_; }
  int value() const { return i_; };
private:
  int i_;
  int dummy_[1024];
};

int main() {
  // performance difference between auto and std::function
  { 
    auto less1 = [](const auto& p1, const auto& p2) {
      return *p1 < *p2;
    };
    std::cout << "size of less1: " << sizeof(less1) << endl;

    function<bool(const std::unique_ptr<Widget>&,
                  const std::unique_ptr<Widget>&)>
        less2 = [](const std::unique_ptr<Widget>& p1,
                   const std::unique_ptr<Widget>& p2) {
          return *p1 < *p2;
        };
    std::cout << "size of less2: " << sizeof(less2) << endl;

    {
      // auto
      std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Widget>> ws1;
      for (auto i = 0; i < 1024*100; ++i) {
        ws1.emplace_back(new Widget(std::rand()));
      }

      auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      std::sort(ws1.begin(), ws1.end(), less1);
      auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      cout << ws1[0].get()->value() << " time: " << (end - start).count() << endl;
    }

    {
      // std::function
      // 25% slower than using auto
      std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Widget>> ws2;
      for (auto i = 0; i < 1024*100; ++i) {
        ws2.emplace_back(new Widget(std::rand()));
      }

      auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      std::sort(ws2.begin(), ws2.end(), less2);
      auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      cout << ws2[0].get()->value() << " time: " << (end - start).count() << endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

it's from https://github.com/danielhongwoo/mec/blob/master/item5/item5.cpp

I think this code shows me using `std::function` is slower than using auto. But not usage of memory. I just want to prove it with some real code.

Comment: duplicate of [What is the performance overhead of std::function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057382/what-is-the-performance-overhead-of-stdfunction)

Comment: Note that when talking about overhead of `std::function` (i.e. that `std::function` is "heavy"), usually the performance overhead is meant. Its memory overhead will be minor (around 2 extra pointers, I'd guess).

Answer (score 10):

`std::function` can store an arbitrary callable. In therefore has to engage in *type erasure* to be able to store something of an arbitrary type. This can require dynamic allocation in the general case, and it definitely requires an indirect call (either a virtual call or a call through a function pointer) on each invocation of `operator ()`.

The type of a lambda expression is **not** `std::function`, it's an unnamed class type with `operator()` defined (the lambda's *closure type*). Using `auto a` to store a lambda makes the type of `a` this precise closure type, which has no overhead.

Answer (score 2):

The memory cost for `std::function` is true. As I tested on a RHEL 64bit machine, it is 32 bytes, while a lambda only takes 1 byte. But for runtime efficiency, the comments in the original cost cannot be reproduced.

With `g++ -std=c++17 -O2`, I got `std::function` much faster than lambda actually. With `g++ -std=c++14 -O2`, the results are close but lambda are still behind.

```
size of less1 as lambda: 1
size of less2 as function : 32
3722 time lambda sort: 47979086
6700 time function sort: 45291861
```