# How to declare the type of the closure that takes string, returns void?

Tags: c++, closures, c++14

I have a closure as a global variable that must just take a string (and log it):

```
auto log_info =  [] (const std::string & str) { /* statements */ };
```

Now I want to make a field of the object instead, and now compiler requires me to specify the actual type. Which type it is? Here are the declarations I tried without much success:

```
[] log_info =  [] (const std::string & str) 
[] (const std::string & str) log_info =  [] (const std::string & str)
(const std::string & str) log_info =  [] (const std::string & str)
```

I also tried to guess the type from the compiler error messages but seems firm with the secret:

```
int log_info =  [] (const std::string & str)
```

: invalid user-defined conversion from ‘’ to ‘int’

It is a references to the closure that takes a const std::& string and returns void. How to declare such a type, or I need a different approach?

Comment: the actual type of a lambda isn't known. you need to deduce it with auto or template but if you have an empty closure your lambda will be convertible to a function pointer

Comment: have a look at [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) to see if it does what you need.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker OP has shown nothing that requires `std::function` exept if field means container

Comment: @Tyker I think you meant to say "empty capture clause". That seems to be the case here, so you can store it in a function pointer of type `void (*variable_name)(const std::string &)`

Comment: Umm... If it's capture-less, why not have a regular function instead?

Comment: @Tyker : I might have read more into the question than was intended by the OP, which is why I made it a comment. If there's no need for a generic function wrapper, then `std::function` is indeed not needed, and a simple function pointer should be sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

Because the lambda you show has no state, it can implicitly be converted to a function pointer like this:

```
struct A {
   /* Your member variable declaration: */
   void (*closure) (const std::string&);

   /* Initialize it with a lamdba. */
   A() : closure([](const std::string&){}) {}
};
```

The above snippet will fail when you put state in the capture. Then, you might want to switch to a class template:

```
template <class Fct> struct B {
   B(Fct&& f) : closure(std::forward<Fct>(f)) {}

   Fct closure;
};
```

Here, the lamdba must be passed upon instantiation and for the type being deduced by the compiler, C++17 is required:

```
B b{[](const std::string&){}};
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what were you planning for making the class a template? There would be no way for the user to specify the type if the class is initializing the member itself unless they use something type-erased, at which point you could do that directly. If the lambda has captures, the best I've got is making it an actual class with a spellable type.

Comment: @chris I wasn't planning anything, but referring to a template solution is usually considered good practice :P You're right, of course. Injecting the lamdba via the constructor would in any case be the better use case compared to hard-code it in the instance initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Is `std::function<void(const std:string)>` what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
  std::function<void(const std::string&)> log_info = [](const std::string& str) {
    /* Statements */
  };
```

Thanks for giving a hint to look at std::function.

Comment: `std::function` is not without some serious overhead. You should bear that in mind.

Comment: re. performance concerns : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057382/what-is-the-performance-overhead-of-stdfunction