# Is it possible to save a function pointer with arguments for later use?

Tags: c++, function, class, c++11, function-pointers

Yesterday, I was trying to program a basic renderer where the renderer controlled when data was loaded into a shader without the renderable object knowing anything about the shader being used. Being a stubborn person (and not running on enough sleep), I spent several hours trying to have function pointers sent to the renderer, saved, then run at the appropriate time. It wasn't until later that I realized what I was trying to build was a message system. It got me wondering, though, is it possible to save *function pointers* with arguments directly to be run at a later time in c++.

My original idea looked something like this:

```
// set up libraries and variables
Renderer renderer();
renderable obj();
mat4 viewMatrix();
// renderer returns and object id
int objID = renderer.loadObj(obj)

int main()
{
  //do stuff
  while(running)
  {
    //do stuff
    renderer.pushInstruction(//some instruction);
    renderer.render();
  }
}

// functionPtr.h
#include <functional>

class storableFunction
{
  public:
  virtual ~storableFunction = 0;
  virtual void call() = 0;
};

template<class type>
class functionPtr : public storableFunction
{
  std::function<type> func;
public:
  functionPtr(std::function<type> func)
    : func(func) {}
  void call() { func(); }
};

//renderer.h
struct  modelObj
{
  // model data and attached shader obj
  std::queue<storableFunction> instruction;
}

class renderer
{
  std::map<int, modelObj> models;
public:
    // renderer functions
    void pushInputDataInstruction(int id, //function, arg1, arg2);
    // this was overloaded because I did not know what type the second argument  would be
    // pushInputDataInstruction implementation in .cpp
    {
      models[id].instruction.push(functionPtr(std::bind(//method with args)))
    }
  void render();
};

//implantation in .cpp
{
  for(// all models)
  //bind all data
  applyInstructions(id);
  // this would call all the instructrions using functionptr.call() in the queue and clear the queue
  draw();
  // unbind all data
}
```

I realize that boost probably supports some kind of similar functionality, but I wanted to avoid using *boost*.

Is something like this possible, what would the general design look like, and what would it even be used for seeing as a message bus is a much more proven design pattern for something like this?

Comment: [`std::bind` is along the lines of what you're looking for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

Comment: Or just use a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), so long as you capture by value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to save function pointers with arguments directly to be
>   run at a later time in c++.

**Yes**, it is.

First of all, if you are in already C++11 or latter you do not need boost to deal with your current problem.

The simplest and intuitive approach is to, make all your functions as a lambda function (i.e, return lambdas) and store to your

```
std::queue<storableFunction> instruction;
```

You will find a detailed explanation about lambdas here: [What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)

---

Providing `storableFunction` idea is good as you can tell the function pointer type explicitly for each member functions which you are storing to the `modelObj`.

However, in case of thinking of storing to some STL containers, you need to use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), with some [type erasure overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057382/what-is-the-performance-overhead-of-stdfunction), which can deal with [the different lambda functions](http://www.riptutorial.com/cplusplus/example/10481/-function--overhead), capable of capturing variables in scope).

Here is <kbd>**[an example code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nMyjMw7Rt1yB21Sa)**</kbd> with `std::vector`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
  int arg1 = 4;
  std::string arg2 = "String";

  std::vector<std::function<void()>> vecFunPtr
  {
    [](int arg1 = 1){ std::cout << arg1 << std::endl; },
    [](float arg1 = 2.0f){ std::cout << arg1 << std::endl; },
    [](double arg1 = 3.0){ std::cout << arg1 << std::endl; },
    [&arg1, &arg2](){ std::cout << arg1 << " " << arg2 << std::endl; }
  };

  for(const auto& funs: vecFunPtr) funs(); // call the stored lambdas
  return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
1
2
3
4 String
```

---

In your case, `Renderer` can be written as follows. One thing to note that, you need to make a bit workaround for passing different arguments to the member functions(or lambda captures for sure.)

*Side-note*: [Here](https://blog.demofox.org/2015/02/25/avoiding-the-performance-hazzards-of-stdfunction/) you will find some tips to avoid the performance issues due to `std::function`, which might be helpful.

```
class Renderer
{
  typedef std::queue<std::function<void()>> modelObj; // you might need modelObj for only this class
  typedef std::function<void()> fFunPtr;              // typedef for void(*)() using std::function
  std::map<int, modelObj> models;
public:
    // renderer functions can be written like returning a lambda
    fFunPtr rFun1(int arg1)    { return [](int arg1 = 1){ std::cout << arg1 << std::endl; }; }
    fFunPtr rFun2(double arg1) { return [](float arg1 = 2.0f){ std::cout << arg1 << std::endl; }; }
    // function to store them for latter use
    void pushInputDataInstruction(const int id, const fFunPtr& funPtr)
    {
      models[id].push(funPtr); 
    }
};

int main()
{
  Renderer objRender;
  //do stuff
  while(/*condition*/)
  {
    //do stuff
    objRender.pushInstruction(/* id number, function pointer*/)
    renderer.render();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see that makes a lot of sense! I'm still wondering is there any reason why you would use this design pattern over a more traditional message system?

Comment: @JustinW Simple reason: the flexibility of Lambda functions which has its definition available, where we need them. On the other side, you can also look for signal slote mechanisum, such as [vdk-signal](https://github.com/vdksoft/signals), [boost-signals2](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.signals2), which actually works as you intended. ( if you do not wannt to use lambdas)

Answer (score 6):

`std::bind` is one approach, but if you have access to C++ 11 and later, you may want to consider using lambdas instead. Scott Meyer recommends their use over std::bind (in most cases) in *Effective Modern C++*.

A lambda has three parts:

- the `[]` part, which identifies the values or references to capture,
- the `()` part, which identifies the arguments that will be provided later, when the lambda is invoked.
- the `{}` part, which identifies what to do with the captured values and parameters

Simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

void printValue(int x) {
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int x = 23;

    // [x] means 'capture x's value, keep it for later'
    // (int y) means 'I'll provide y when I invoke the lambda'
    auto storedFunction = [x](int y){return printValue(x + y);};

    x = 15;

    // Now we invoke the lamda, with y = 2
    // Result: 25 (23 + 2), even if x was changed after the lambda was created
    storedFunction(2); 
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to capture a reference to `x`, use `[&x]`. In the example above, the result would then be 17 (i.e. 15 + 2). If you do use a reference, be careful not to let `x` fall out of scope before the `storedFunction`, as it would then become a dangling reference to garbage data.

Most compilers support C++ 11 now, but you may need to add the support explicitly in the project settings:

- Visual Studio: Project Properties/C++/Language/C++ Language Standard
- gcc: `--std=c++11` (or 14, or 17...)
- CMake also allows you to set the standard: `set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)`

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, you create a lambda that calls the function that you want then save the lambda. Is that correct?

Comment: To clarify: during the lambda's creation, the function is not called right away. Creating a lambda puts together the information required to make the call (parameters + function call(s)). Then the lambda is "called"/invoked using ().

Comment: If I recall correctly (big hand waving here), under the hood, creating a lambda creates a class that stores all the values and references passed into [], and creates an operator() that takes the arguments described in the () at the beginning of the lambda. The {} body of the lambda becomes operator()'s logic. Basically.

Comment: To clarify: `std::bind` also requires C++11.