# callback in C++ struct

Tags: c++, callback, function-pointers, std-function

I have been trying to implement a callback function in c++. Within a class, I have a struct, a number of methods, and a method that creates an instance of the struct with one of the other methods as its argument.

The struct has many other variables, but an illustration is depicted here:

```
class MYCLASS
{
public:
    MYCLASS();

    struct TEST{
        std::function<int(int)> foo;
    };

    int plus(int x){
        return x + 1;
    }

    int minus(int x){
        return x - 1;
    }

    void sim(){
        TEST T;             // make an instance of TEST
        T.foo = plus(5);    // assign TEST.foo a function (plus or minus)  
        T.foo();            // call the method we assigned
    }
};
```

Within the `sim` method, I want to create an instance of `test` and give it either `plus` or `minus`, depending on some criterion. Both lines where I try and give the instance `T` a `plus` function and subsequently call it are incorrect.

Comment: `plus(5)` is not a method. It's a result of calling `plus` with arg `5` which in your case is simply `6`. What you want is `T.foo = plus; int result = T.foo(5);`.

Comment: Thank you, this gives me the following `error: reference to non-static member function must be
      called
                T.foo = plus; `

Comment: right, both your functions have to be static. Or you have to wrap the call into "this" catching lambda: `T.foo = [this](int a) { return this->plus(a); }`. Note that this is no longer safe. Your `MYCLASS` has to outlive `TEST` otherwise UB

Comment: @freakish thank you, that worked! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delay the call to `T.foo`, then you could use a lambda like this:

```
    T.foo = [this](int x) { return plus(x); };
    T.foo(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Option - 1

If the member functions  `plus()` and `minus()` are simple enough like you have shown, you can make them as lambda functions inside the struct `TEST`.
Since the **capture-less lambdas** can be stored **in typed function pointers**, the following will do what you want.
[See live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1OBXU0nK8JAeD0ky)

```
#include <iostream>
class MYCLASS
{
    int m_var = 5; // just for demonstration
public:
    MYCLASS() = default;
    struct TEST
    {
        using fPtrType = int(*)(int);   // function pointer type
        const fPtrType foo1 = [](int x) { return x + 1; };  // plus function
        const fPtrType foo2 = [](int x) { return x - 1; };  // minus function
    };

    void sim()
    {
        TEST T;
        std::cout << "Answer from int PLUS(int): " << T.foo1(m_var) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Answer from int MINUS(int): " << T.foo2(m_var) << std::endl;
    }
};
```

---

### Option - 2

If the above alter a lot in your code, use typed function pointer again for member functions and do as follows; which will avoid **unnecessary copying**(by capturing) the class instance to the lambda and **template instantiation** and other **[performance issues](https://blog.demofox.org/2015/02/25/avoiding-the-performance-hazzards-of-stdfunction/)** comes along [with `std::function`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057382/what-is-the-performance-overhead-of-stdfunction/9088690#9088690) as well.

[See live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lYJOrY6nqf94X5mx)

```
#include <iostream>    
class MYCLASS
{
    using fPtrType = int(MYCLASS::*)(int); // class member function pointer type
public:
    MYCLASS() = default;
    struct TEST { fPtrType foo = nullptr; };

    int plus(int x) { return x + 1; }
    int minus(int x) { return x - 1; }

    void sim()
    {
        TEST T;
        T.foo = &MYCLASS::plus; // now you can
        std::cout << "Answer from int PLUS(int): " << (this->*T.MYCLASS::TEST::foo)(5) << std::endl;
                                                     //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ syntax would be a bit ugly
        // later same ptr variable for minus()
        T.foo = &MYCLASS::minus;
        int answer = (this->*T.MYCLASS::TEST::foo)(5);
        std::cout << "Answer from int MINUS(int): " << answer << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MYCLASS obj;
    obj.sim();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Answer from int PLUS(int): 6
Answer from int MINUS(int): 4
```