# What's the shortest path in C++11 (or newer) to create an RAII wrapper without having to write a new class?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17, raii

Often I'm in a situation where I need a simple RAII wrapper, but I wouldn't want to create a whole new class for this for many reasons including time constraints and organization problems. My quick-n-dirty solution is the following.

Say I want to make sure that by the end of the scope, I want a boolean to switch back to its original state:

```
bool prevState = currState;
currState      = newState;
std::unique_ptr<int, std::function<void(int*)>> txEnder(new int(0), [&prevState](int* p) {
    currState = prevState;
    delete p;
});
```

This solution works fine, but the dirty part is the necessity to allocate and deallocate that integer just to make `unique_ptr` work and call the custom destructor at destruction.

Is there a cleaner way to do this without having to write a whole class, and get rid of the `new` for the dummy `int`?

Comment: Not sure you need to allocate anything?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher You need to allocate to ensure a non-zero pointer. A non-zero pointer (non-null pointer) is basically what triggers destruction.

Comment: What about writing a simple class once and give it a lambda as you want at construction and call that at the destructor? Similar like a lock guard.

Comment: i guess you are not looking for boosts `BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT`, right?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm trying to avoid writing new classes. We can argue on why, but I wanna see if there's a way around it.

Comment: @user463035818 Never heard of it. I'm looking into the answer now. It has it.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I am not talking about new classes (<- plural), just a single one you can use for all of these cases. It would be very simple, and you even can make it a template if you need to have stuff forwarded to the lambda.

Comment: are you sure that the deleter is only called for non-null pointers? I couldnt find anything on that

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I know, buddy. I have one that I discussed before on Stackoverflow (I call SmartHandle). But, again, I don't have the freedom to do that in all the projects I work at depending on many circumstances, ranging from hastiness down to project organization problems.

Comment: @user463035818 From my understanding of smart pointers, they are destroyed with something like `if(!ptr) delete ptr;`. I don't see how else.

Comment: I really dont know but I would expect that this is what happens when you dont provide your own deleter, while a custom deleter is called always

Comment: @user463035818 calling `delete` on `nullptr` is a noop. IRC, it's UB to do anything else if you overload it.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist What a pity if you can't do the necessary work because of such silly circumstances. But I know that kind of situation.

Comment: @user463035818 _while a custom deleter is called always_ Are you sure? Standard says otherwise: http://eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr.single#dtor-2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little bit better than yours: You can use `&prevState` in the custom destructor without deleting it, so you do not need to `new` and `delete` something:

```
void foo(bool & currState, bool newState)
{
    bool prevState = currState;
    currState      = newState;
    std::unique_ptr<bool, std::function<void(bool*)>> txEnder(&prevState, [&prevState, &currState](bool* p) {
        currState = prevState;
    });
    cout << "currState: " << currState << endl;
}
```

You also forgot to capture `currState` in the lambda.

Here is an example: https://ideone.com/DH7vZu

Comment: This is perfect. I don't know how this didn't occur to me. I'm just being a little paranoid thinking whether this breaks any rules!

Comment: Interesting solution for the problem.

Comment: I would just note that this solution might not be the most efficient one, since `std::function` applies type erasure, which implies dynamic memory allocations (possibly small-buffer optimized) and virtual function overhead (see, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/9088690/580083). "Classic" ScopeGuard, such as that from Boost, might be more efficient.

Comment: @DanielLangr How about [this solution](https://ideone.com/wFMT8N)? Is this super-perfect?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist It's better IMO, but I wouldn't call it super-perfect. Unique pointers are unique pointers and scope guards are scope guards. Both can be used in multiple scenarios, but primarily, for the functionality you want are the latter ones. Unfortunately, they are not part of the Standard so we have to make trade-offs.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Your solution is better. I have improved slightly by not relying on a local bool (easily copy pastable to different context). https://stackoverflow.com/a/53742232/

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Also note that there is a proposal for adding scope guards (`std::scope_...`) into the Stadndard library: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0052r9.pdf.

Comment: @DanielLangr I would appreciate it more if they add destructors to lamdas... that would be a killer feature!

Comment: Here's an arguably a more efficient variant (no std::function). https://ideone.com/NnU6zf

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html)

```
auto prevState{currState};
currState = newState;
BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT(&currState, &prevState)
{
     currState = prevState;
} BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END
```

Comment: Yay. Boost. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `std::function`. It creates a lot of code including vtables. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/XgDoHz
If you absolutely don't want to use any external class or function, do below:

```
bool foo_2() {
    bool f = false;
    auto eos = [&](void*){
        f = true;
    };
    std::unique_ptr<void, decltype(eos)> h{&eos,std::move(eos)};
    return f;
}
```

If you are ok with a little reusable function, below works. This abstracts the unused `void*`.

*C++14 or later*

```
template<class F>
auto call_at_end_of_scope(F&& f){
    auto eos = [f{std::forward<F>(f)}](void*){f();};
    return std::unique_ptr<void, decltype(eos)>{&eos,std::move(eos)};
}

bool foo_3() {
    bool f = false;
    auto handle = call_at_end_of_scope([&](){
        f = true;
    });
    return f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `gsl::finally`? Library is not so heavy as boost and `finally` does not use `std::function`, so can be easly inlined. Also no dynamic allocation of `std::unique_ptr`

```
using namespace std;

void foo(bool & currState, bool newState)
{
    auto revertState = gsl::finally([prevState = currState, &currState]{
        currState = prevState;
    });
    currState = newState;       
    cout << "currState: " << currState << endl;
}


int main() {
    bool state = false;
    foo(state, true);
    cout << "state: " << state << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Online example: https://ideone.com/Xi1izz (with copied `gsl::finally`, since `#include <gsl/gsl>` is not available here)

Comment: Your solution may be correct, but the challenge was to have the shortest path. The answer that is accepted is super-short and doesn't have any dynamic allocation.