# Callable being required to be static in C++ class template

Tags: c++, templates, static, callable

I would like to have the following class setup in a program:

- A class that implements a buffer. This buffer, when full, would spawn a thread that makes a callback to handle what to do with the full buffer.
- A base class template that includes a buffer object. Implements the callback function, which makes a call to a virtual function defined in a derived class.
- A derived class that inherits from base class and implements what to do with the data.

First, the minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

template <typename T>
class CallbackBuffer
{
    public:

        std::vector<T> buffer;
        void (*callback)(std::vector<T>);
        std::thread writerThread;

        CallbackBuffer(int bufferSize = 10)
        {
            buffer.resize(bufferSize);
        }

        void setCallback(void (*cb)(std::vector<T>))
        {
            callback = cb;
        }

        void writeCall()
        {
            writerThread = std::thread(callback, buffer);
        }
};

template <typename T>
class Base
{
    public:

        CallbackBuffer<T> buffer;

        Base()
        {
            buffer.setCallback(bufferHandler);
        }

        void bufferHandler(std::vector<T> v)
        {
            for(auto &i : v)
            {
                write(i);
            }
        }

        virtual void write(T i) = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base<int>
{
    public:

        Derived()
        {
        }

        void write(int i)
        {
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the following compiler error:

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘void Base<T>::bufferHandler(std::vector<T>) [with T = int]’
```

So the compiler needs **bufferHandler** to be static, but if I did that, then I would not have access to the object's members. Is there a way to sort this, or just a horrible idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the class member function so you need to have in your `CallbackBuffer` class something like:

```cpp
void (Base<T>::*callback)(std::vector<T>);

// ...

void setCallback(void (Base<T>::*cb)(std::vector<T>)) {
    callback = cb;
}
```

and in `Base` class:

```cpp
Base() {
    buffer.setCallback(&Base<T>::bufferHandler);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tLgAZSW9ABk8tTADljAI0zEQk3gAdUCwuto9QxNzUh8/NTpbeycjV3dPRWVMVQCGAmZiAiDjU04LJRVI2nTMgmjHFzcPXgUMrJyQ/MV68rtKuOrPAEpFVANiZA4AcikAZjtkQywAanExnQA3FKJieexxMwBBccnpzDmF9TriTGYjdc2dyQnaKYNZ%2BZ0CBFPmdEvtq4JMIy9hH6HZ4ATy8WnOBwAKp8tlNmAoFDNpPDMPNZF9tj8/gCDk8CKDwUYoTC4QiZjo2KxnMxkABraQGKhUNxXcQAdnRWxm3JmXgMzlYeGQIFZ2x54pmdXQIBAy1UJCe0LG2BmzkZzLWY05Ep5i1QeHQMwgyKUivWMoAVCxWFSabTuhApTK5aszcrumirjruU6QC83oaAO7EQhuSGvM4fLWinZi70Um3UukMpluCB2Aiq9VuBh4ABeuLGABEZvkPXGdeztd7xWrU8QAHSnPwFiB1jW5gse6MViXsosxmt6g2SzDZSlJ2kQYeG40ot3YS3IZwO30uhULJXYbrlrneqtems8622umHEvLz298X9wfemczYOhhOsCC7msH6/ep8/YjhgPnpKBDSn6EbvBAJ6TqQWb1t21aVmyA5fIhV6xlsWL/MwgJ4gStAQjMW5XKSiImqiyHwby/KCsKd46i%2Bk4phqC4wUxPZoTWpFvoeCEUTW7ZuA2SjjomdoQFIABspELjK/HEAAEiI6DsMQcHcX2KEYnuOoPrJCnaMpjrAc6KwbjoW4zIs777hyak1jQxAQMwBhEHMkjiXgMwgBZVlHnMNlfr5P6YOmqkBepSFaeFtESoseBZAYbAWfqQYhj8ECQjMeDdIBZiobebFEcIZJFm4eDLIaXl8gKQpIvORz0DCn6RVV1EippNYlSG5VcWFTUfhp7H3slj6pcFGaZT56m8d6vpoM5QJPJlC0LEBIFWKwqH9RF%2BWclc41GMwdg9Ts/mRZ1ZWYIaUYUacBADLQMy5QViHDL0rAgMMACswykKYwxmD9qAfTochyJK/SDLiNycD9BAfQDO6kLSICfZIDbcOJbmfQAnNjblmJIkifWyn1CB93A/X9AOkEDww/QoIAWHD/2vaQcCwDAiAoKgfx4Mp5CUGgvPKSAwDiWMpBUHzv4M228M/c4diZMCH0w6QQtEvQADytCsCrLOkFgB2iOw8uG3FKwXQzBuYAAHikzkjNTGbKGbgrOMQyt6FgquwyGRjy70ND0EwbAcDw/CCMIogoKDMhCHgzgM5AvSoF4xTWwAtFK8xFhIMhyJwauFJbGgQFYjR5JY2gVLE8SCOE/h0JXDe%2BE3tC11U7icEkRRpK0Lc9yXqR0KUWSd503ctGUg/T%2BP7R19UnC9AoENDFwb0fd9v1m7TtsABziZn4ncDMwDIMgMziQ2YxGrghAkK5Yw9%2BSPNeHzbhP8v5Jx9IsOB70BAkZqhviRuYCw71hgU1IAHT6FgqaAw%2BvTRmpBmYIzZpzCASB%2BgED5AQAWEE34fynpdB%2BU9g6MGtOHXgwZmBeF9pvL6lNd4fXGJwR8hAEAzAPkfE%2BZ8L5Xxvv/FmiMgHvBAb0ZG%2BQIHkx%2BrA%2BBLC6aKBQWg16kiQDcDZOjbgnBPqfQxmMQxJ8xj7zJsMMYzCDa02EQjRhkhLHU2saggBpBljED8BobgQA%3D%3D)

Comment: Nice. How is that there's no problem with duplicate Base declarations? Would this cause a circular header dependecy if every class is defined in a different file?

Comment: @derkomai forward declarations are a common thing and shouldn't cause any circular dependency

Answer (score 1):

Member function pointers have different type than regular functions, that's why your code does not work. What you may want is using `std::function` instead of raw pointers:

```cpp
#include <functional>

//...
std::function<void(std::vector<T>)> callback;

// ...

void setCallback(const std::function<void(std::vector<T>)>& cb) {
    callback = cb;
}
```

and pass it like that:

```cpp
Base() {
    buffer.setCallback([this](auto& vec){ this->bufferHandler(vec); });
}
```

IMHO this is much more readable and flexible than passing around member pointers

Comment: This might be more readable but `std::function` are more expensive than the member pointers.

Comment: @NutCracker, could you elaborate a little more on this, please? Also, it seems that auto in lambdas require c++14 (not a problem here).

Comment: @derkomai check this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9088690/5517378)

Comment: @NutCracker thanks, both solutions are 100% valid, but i'm  certainly more into the cheapest one for now.