# error: cannot convert ‘<lambda(double)>’ to ‘double (*)(double)’

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, function-pointers, member-functions

I have this error

```
error: cannot convert ‘<lambda(double)>’ to ‘double (*)(double)’
```

From the code

```
void Matrice::mapEmplace(double (*fct)(double))
{
   for (size_t i = 1; i <= nLig; ++i)
      for (size_t j = 1; j <= nCol; ++j)
         (*this)(i, j) = (*fct)((*this)(i, j));
}
```

--

```
void function()
{
   // ...
   bool alea = something;

   // alea results on reading in a file
   utilisation.mapEmplace(
      [alea](double x) -> double {
         return alea ? 1 : 0;
      }
   );
   //....
}
```

When I do not capture `alea` by declaring it global for example, it works. But when I declare `alea` in the scope of my function g++ display this error.

Do you know what is the problem and how I can resolve it by keeping `alea` local to my function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only convert [the capture-less lambda to a c-style function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-capturing-lambda-as-function-pointer/28746827#28746827). In your case, your lambda capture the `alea` by copy, and hence the conversion to function pointer type is not possible.

You have two options:

1. Either use the [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) with some [type-eraser overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057382/what-is-the-performance-overhead-of-stdfunction).
2. Or make the function as a templated one, so that the compiler can deduce the type of lambda.

   ```
   template<typename T>
   void Matrice::mapEmplace(T fct)
   {
      for (size_t i = 1; i <= nLig; ++i)
          for (size_t j = 1; j <= nCol; ++j)
              (*this)(i, j) = fct((*this)(i, j));
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

`std::function` is designed expressly to handle a capturing lambda.  So, replace this:

```
void Matrice::mapEmplace(double (*fct)(double)) {
  for(size_t i = 1; i <= nLig; ++i)
    for(size_t j = 1; j <= nCol; ++j)
      (*this)(i,j) = (*fct)((*this)(i,j));
}
```

with this:

```
void Matrice::mapEmplace(std::function<double(double)> fct) {
  for(size_t i = 1; i <= nLig; ++i)
    for(size_t j = 1; j <= nCol; ++j)
      (*this)(i,j) = fct((*this)(i,j));
}
```

And add `#include <functional>` at the top of your cpp file.

Comment: `std::function` is a rather heavyweight option. In general, it has to allocate memory to hold the function object. In this case, the captured object is a bool and will fit inside the small buffer optimization. However, I would probably go for the template in this case.

Comment: @Paul Sanders It works perfectly thanks.