# Passing a member function pointer as an argument to a template method

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda, std-function

I am trying to write a templated method that will accept a member function pointer as an argument.

Here is an example class, including my latest attempt to write said template method:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   int myMethod() { return 1; }

   template<typename T> 
   T call(std::function<T(MyClass*)> m)
   {
      return m(this);
   }
};
```

My goal is to be able to do the following (or something very similar in syntax):

```
MyClass m;
auto result = m.call(&MyClass::myMethod);
```

So far with my attempt above, I can do:

```
MyClass m;
std::function<int(MyClass*)> f = &MyClass::myMethod;
auto result = m.call(f);
```

I was surprised I was not even able to wrap that into a single line. `m.call(&MyClass::myMethod)` this does not compile. Why?

I am sure there is a way to get the behaviour I want, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What output are you getting when you run the code?

Comment: Something about deducing the type of `T` I think. This, which specifies `T` explicitly, compiles `auto result = m.call<int>([](MyClass* h){return h->myMethod();});`

Comment: When I compile with the syntax I want, I get `candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<type-parameter-0-0 (MyClass *)>' against 'int (MyClass::*)()'`

I am trying to avoid having to specify return types etc, want as automatic as possible. Technically I can do that, but it's horrible syntax: `m.call(std::function<std::result_of<decltype(&MyClass::myMethod)(MyClass)>::type(MyClass*)>(&MyClass::myMethod))`

Comment: Why did you pass "this" as argument when you called 'm'  in member function template call.  i. e m(this) ;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently it cannot deduce `T` (template parameter from a very deduced ctor argument).

If your goal is to simply do it in one call you can change method definition to something like

```cpp
    template<class F> auto call(F &&f) {
        return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), this);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

> I was surprised I was not even able to wrap that into a single line.
> `m.call(&MyClass::myMethod)` ... this does not compile. Why?

The member function pointer has the following type

```
<return-type>(ClassType::*)(<args>)<specifiers-if-any>
```

meaning `&MyClass::myMethod` has the type

```
int(MyClass::*)(void)
```

This is not equal to the type `std::function<int(MyClass*)>` and the compiler can not directly deduce it, hence the compiler error.

However, if we **explicit**ly mention the template type, it can be deduced to  `std::function<int(MyClass*)>`, with *[some type erasur overheads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057382/what-is-the-performance-overhead-of-stdfunction)*. Meaning you could mention the template parameter explicitly like as follows:

```
/* const */ int result = m.call<int>(&MyClass::myMethod);    // works!
//                             ^^^^^^ -> mention T == int here!
```

**([See Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6hdpL-))**

---

> I'm sure there's a way to get the behaviour[...]

If you do not use `std::function` rather the normal (templated) *member function pointer type*, this will work.

```
template<typename T>
T call(T(MyClass::* m)())
{
   return (this->*m)();
   // or
   // std::invoke(m, this); // in C++17
}
```

Now you could

```
/* const */ int result = m.call(&MyClass::myMethod);
```

**([See Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ZQ95GS))**

---

If the syntax is confusing you could provide a template type alias for the member function pointer like this.

```
class MyClass 
{
   // template type alias
   template<typename T> using MemFunctionPtrT = T(MyClass::*)();
public:
   // other codes

   template<typename T>
   T call(MemFunctionPtrT<T> m) // use the alias type like
   {
      return (this->*m)();
      // or
      // std::invoke(m, this); // in C++17
   }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this is also a useful explanation of how to do the template function definition correctly to accept the the member function pointer!