# c++ shared_ptr<map<int, int>> initialized with different comparison function, any way?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap

if I have a field in class like below,

```
class MyClass {
public:
    shared_ptr<map<int, int>> my_map;
}
```

The default `map<int,int>`'s comparison function is `less<int>`, but I would like to initialize `my_map` as

```
my_map = make_shared<map<int, int, greater<int>>>();
```

sometimes,

This doesnt compile, what other way I can have a `shared_ptr<map<int, int>>` that in two different object of `MyClass`, one has `less<int>` and the other have `greater<int>` so that the `my_map` in each object is sorted differently?

Comment: You should include the error message from your compiler, verbatim.  That would point our your typo.

Comment: What error do you get, maybe you just need to separate the two `>` brackets (if you are compiling against a standard < c++17).

Comment: Can you stick your whole code in the question? Makes it easier to see what might be wrong.

Comment: May I ask why do you need to `shared_ptr<>` your `map`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what other way I can have a `shared_ptr<map<int, int>>` that in two different object of `MyClass`, one has `less<int>` and the other have `greater<int>` so that the `my_map` in each object is sorted differently?

You can specify `std::function` as the template argument for comparator as

```
std::shared_ptr<std::map<int, int, std::function<bool(int,int)>>> my_map;
```

and initialize it with `std::less<int>`

```
my_map = std::make_shared<std::map<int, int, std::function<bool(int,int)>>>(std::less<int>{});
```

or `std::greater<int>`.

```
my_map = std::make_shared<std::map<int, int, std::function<bool(int,int)>>>(std::greater<int>{});
```

Comment: It woukd be [expensive to do `std::function<bool(int,int)>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057382/what-is-the-performance-overhead-of-stdfunction), where it fits with just `uing functionPointer = bool(*)(int)(int)`.

Comment: @Const But `std::less` and `std::greater` can't be used with function pointer.

Comment: thanks for this answer, i have tested, it works, just a further question, I believe you are refering to this constructor  `explicit map (const key_compare& comp,  const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());` here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/ ? How did you know that the return type is `std::map<int, int, std::function<bool(int,int)>>`? I cant find this anywhere in the official doc.

Comment: @tesla1060 Yes, that constructor is used. The type, i.e. `std::map<int, int, std::function<bool(int,int)>>` is specified as the template argument when calling `std::make_shared`, then we'll get a `shared_ptr` pointing to `std::map<int, int, std::function<bool(int,int)>>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom comparator, something like:

```
struct my_comparator {

     bool the_other_way=false;

     my_comparator(bool flag) : the_other_way{flag} {}

     bool operator()(int a, int b) const
     {
         return the_other_way ? a > b: a < b;
     }
};
```

And construct a `std::map<int, int, my_comparator>`.

`std::map` has an overloaded constructor that takes an instance of the comparator object as a parameter. You can simply construct each individual map, accordingly.

```
typedef std::map<int, int, my_comparator> my_map;

my_map m1{my_comparator{false}};

my_map m2{my_comparator{true}};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize the internal `map` with a different comparator for different objects, you can template the class to accept a comparison object, like this:

```
template<typename Compare = std::less<int>>
class MyClass 
{
  public:
    std::shared_ptr<std::map<int, int, Compare>> my_map;
};
```

and then create different objects:

```
int main()
{
    MyClass<> a;   // std::less<int> by default
    MyClass<std::greater<int>> b;
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7a4hqr).

Answer (score 0):

The comparator is part of the type declaration, so your member would need to include the comparator type:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    shared_ptr<map<int, int, greater<int>>> my_map;
}
```

Also, you are missing a '>' in the assignment. It should be:

```
my_map = make_shared<map<int, int, greater<int>>>();
```

See cigien's answer if you want to templatize your class to use different comparators (as the question implies).