# In c++ does greater_equal<double> have a type of function<bool (double, double)>

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

my understanding is that `greater_equal<double>` is a functor that has a signature of `function<bool (double, double)>`, so I have tried to perform the following,

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<std::function<bool (double, double)>> f;
    auto f1 =make_shared<greater_equal<double>>();
    auto f2 = make_shared<less_equal<double>>();
    f = f1;
}
```

To my surprise this wont compile because,

> '': cannot convert from 'const
> std::shared_ptrstd::greater_equal<double>' to
> 'std::shared_ptr<std::function<bool (double,double)>>'

I am not sure why,
what I need is similar to the spirit in the above snippet, I will have a member field of function, `std::shared_ptr<std::function<bool (double, double)>>` and I need to assign either `<greater_equal<double>` or `less_equal<double>` base on some condition, how should I achieve this?

Comment: What's to be surprised about there? It is a type which overloads `operator()`, it is not implicitly convertible to a `std::function`. You need a lambda if that's what you want to do. The overloaded operator might be convertible if you know the actual incantation, but the object itself is not a lambda.

Comment: @TanveerBadar Why isn't it convertible? It is (an instance of that type, that is). OP just does it incorrectly.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Color me surprised then. :) If it is supposed to be convertible, then this might be an issue with the compiler OP is using. Or that.

Comment: Note that the problem is with `shared_ptr` here. You can store `std::greater_equal` into `std::function<bool(double, double)>`. But in`shared_ptr` construction/assignment, you can work only with objects that have [_compatible_ pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr), which is not your case.

Comment: @TanveerBadar It is convertible since `std::function` has a corresponding (non-explicit) converting constructor. You can easily write `std::function<bool(double, double)> f = std::greater_equal<double>{};`.

Comment: If you [look it up](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater_equal), you will see that your assumption about the type is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you wrote would work if `std::greater_equal<double>` and `std::less_equal<double>` inherited from `std::function<bool(double, double)>`, which they don't do.

But since `std::function<bool(double, double)` is constructible from an instance of `std::greater_equal<double>` (and `less_equal`), you can do this instead:

```
auto f1 = std::make_shared<std::function<bool(double, double)>>(std::greater_equal<double>{});
```

---

But I don't think you want `std::function` in the first place.

> `greater_equal<double>` is a functor that has a signature of `function<bool (double, double)>`

Yes, its `operator()` has `(double, double)` parameters and returns `bool`, but it's not related to `std::function`.

`std::function` is a wrapper class that can store any object it considers to be callable. It accepts slight variations in signature (e.g. even though `less/greater_equal` accept parameters by const references, and you told `std::function` that parameters should be passed by value, it still works), and it can store objects with a state (with data members). Those features come [with an overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057382/what-is-the-performance-overhead-of-stdfunction).

---

Judging by

> I need to assign either `greater_equal<double>` or `less_equal<double>` base on some condition

you need none of those `std::function` features.

You could rather use a function pointer (which requires signatures to match exactly, and can't store any state):

```
bool (*ptr)(double, double) = [](double a, double b)
{
    return a <= b;
};
```